# how to get the behavior of a search box similar to the WhatsApp's?

Tags: mobile

That is my question, I've been trying to reach with some information through Google but at the end I had to come here to ask you for that, the behavior I mean: you focus on the search box which is going to extend up to the top of the page and overlaps the header, also, you are unable to see the search box at first sigh, you have to scroll up to the top. Any hint or suggestions on how I can reach that behavior ? what is the proper technique ?

I am using Angular with Ionic Framework just in case that want to show me something with jQuery UI.

Comment: This isn't really an angular question.

Comment: I just change the ```tag``` sorry Mr.